# Bundle Install Fails: Error loading Rubygems plugin after I deleted files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

I am new to Ruby and Rails and am trying to get through the [Hartl rails web development tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#fnref-1_17). During the course of the tutorial, I installed homebrew. After running `brew doctor`, homebrew instructed me to delete a handful of files unless I had put them where they were at on purpose. I deleted them and `brew doctor` said I was all clear.

Now, further along in the tutorial I am trying to deploy an app to Heroku. But I've found out that my gemfile.lock file was never updated by `bundle install`. In fact, `bundle install` hadn't been working for me at all. The error output is below. It appears to be related to one of the files I deleted (I base this on the line `Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib`; I remember deleting that file).

How do I fix this? From my research, I think I need to reinstall something, but I can't figure out what. I installed Postgresql, but that did nothing.

Secondarily, was deleting all of those files a huge mistake? How can I get them back (I also can't scroll up enough in my Terminal to see their names)? Would homebrew have worked if I had left them alone even though `brew doctor` raised concerns about them?

```
Wyatts-MacBook-Pro:first_app Wyatt$ bundle installError loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.2.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/Wyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
/Users/Wyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Wyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:245:in `install'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/Wyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `brew install openssl` should get you that library back.

Comment: Didn't work. Still get the same error message.

Comment: Fixed it! I just had to do `brew reinstall openssl` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Nick Veys for this answer:

I just had to run `brew reinstall openssl` to replace the missing library.

Comment: if "reinstall" does not work try running:
1) brew uninstall openssl
2) brew install openssl

Worked for me.